# How to have data in a database with FastAPI persist across multiple nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, database-design, docker-swarm, fastapi

If I use the https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql project generator, how would one be able to persist data across multiple nodes (either with docker swarm or kubernetes)?

As I understand it, any postgresql data in a volumes directory would be different for every node (e.g. every digitalocean droplet). In this case, a user may ask for their data, get directed by traefik to a node with a different volumes directory, and return different information to the case where they may have been directed to another node. Is this correct?

If so, what would be the best approach to have multiple servers running a database work together and have the same data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

On kubernetes, persistent volumes are used to associate storage that is mounted onto pods wherever they are loaded in the cluster and they are managed by providing the cluster with storage classes that map to drivers that map to some kind of SAN storage.

Docker / Docker swarm has similar support for docker volume plugins, but with the ascendancy of K8s there are virtually no active open source projects, and most of the prior commercial SAN driver vendors have migrated to K8s instead.

Nonetheless, depending on your tolerance, you can use a mix of direct nfs / fuse mounts, there are some not entirely abandoned docker volume drivers available in the nfs / glusterfs space.

This issue [moby/moby #39624](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39624) addresses CSI support that we will hopefully see drop in 2021 that will bring swarm back inline with k8s.